# systemtap failure to find trace events on Ubuntu 3.2

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, systemtap

systemtap fails to find trace events, even though all of them are available in directory:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events. Running "perf record sched" finds all the sched trace events without any issue.

System is running:
Linux (none) 3.2.0-48-virtual #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:02:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## stap -l 'kernel.trace("*")

No event found

systemtap finds kernel functions without any issue.

## stap -l 'kernel.function("*")'

..
kernel.function("AUDIT_MODE@/build/buildd/linux-3.2.0/security/apparmor/include/policy.h:311")
kernel.function("BLEND_OP@/build/buildd/linux-3.2.0/crypto/sha256_generic.c:48")
kernel.function("BLOCK_NEXT@/build/buildd/linux-3.2.0/drivers/staging/zram/xvmalloc.c:82")
....

I saw a bug reported on openSUSE:

Bug 800335 - devel:tools/systemtap: Undeclared dependency on libebl1

But libebl1 is part of Elfutils package that is already installed. What could be missing that resulting systemtap not to find trace events.

Thanks,
Amer.

Comment: Try:    `stap --poison-cache -vvv -L 'kernel.trace("*")'`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but it did not help. I ran: # stap --poison-cache -vvv -L 'kernel.trace("*")'. It ran bunch of make but it is still not finding trace points.

Comment: Please report the problem on the mailing list, including that stap -vvv ... output.